# Why does a current carrying wire not attract small magnetic metal pieces?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, conductors

If the current flowing in the wire produces a magnetic field, why are are small pieces of ferromagnetic metals not attracted to the electric wire?

Comment: Are you thinking that metal magnets are the only source of a magnetic field? That isn't the case. At the deepest level, moving charges (current) is the source of a magnetic field. Here is a video on how magnets work. [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Comment: For a practical application of the attraction between metal pieces and current-carrying wires, look for explanations of the operation of a “relay,” which is a common type of electromechanical switch. The click before your furnace turns itself on? The noise of your turn signals blinking on and off? Those clicks are relays opening and closing, and the motion is caused by the interaction you’re asking about.

Comment: Run a larger current or use smaller bits of metal. If an electromagnet takes a few amps and hundreds of turns to produce an easily visible magnetic force, you can't an effect nearly as strong when you have zero turns.

Answer (score 3):

While it’s true that a current carrying wire produces a magnetic field, this wire placed near ferromagnetic metal filings like iron will align themselves with the magnetic field$^1$ (this is a common experiment). Note that this magnetic field circles the wire (it does not terminate into the wire).

Also, the wire carrying the current is itself not a (usually) magnetic/ferromagnetic material. For example, copper, the most frequently used material for wiring, has no magnetic susceptibility.

$^1$ As pointed out by Rob in comments, in a nonuniform magnetic field, iron filings will experience a net *force* (not torque) toward the region where the magnetic field is stronger.

Comment: You’re right that a dipole in an external field feels an aligning torque.  But a dipole in a *nonuniform* field also feels a net force: aligned dipoles can reduce the total energy stored in the field by moving to a region where the field is stronger.

Comment: @rob This is true. But I think the OP is asking about the simplest case - a DC current in the wire meaning the magnetic field does not change with time (if that's what you mean by nonuniform). Also, a magnetic field does decrease with distance (which is probably what you mean by nonuniform), and indeed there is a net force to where the field is stronger.  OP asks why the metals do not "stick" to the wire which is explained above. I might add your point though Rob. Thanks.